# Limit of $ f(z)= e^{-\lambda/z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Im trying to understand whether or not the function $ f(z)= e^{-\lambda/z},  \lambda>0 $
has a limit as z tends to 0 on the complex plane.

I understand that $ f(z)= e^{\lambda/z}$ does not due to how it behaves on the x and y axis respectively,

furthermore, would
$ f(z)= ze^{-\lambda/z}$ have a limit on the complex plane or the right side plane as z tends to 0?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First question: The limit does not exist. Along the sequence $\frac  1n$ the limit is $0$ but along $z=\frac  i n$ the function has modulus $1$.

Second question: Yes, the limit is $0$ if $z \to 0$ within $\{z: \Re z >0\}$ because $|e^{-\lambda /z}|=e^{-\Re \frac {\lambda \overline {z}} {|z|^{2}}} \leq 1$.